# Java MongoDB return null for find() while data exists

Tags: java, mongodb, centos

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"));
```

mongodb log:

```
2019-12-24T02:53:26.104+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:53234 conn1: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|legacy", version: "3.11.0" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_232-b09" }
```

>

```
MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("raizant");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("users");
```

my server log:

```
[02:54:28] [Server thread/INFO]: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:2}] to 127.0.0.1:27017
```

>

```
Document result = collection.find().first();
LOG.info(String.format("result of first %s", result));
```

my server log:

```
[02:54:28] [Server thread/INFO]: result of first null
```

But the data exists when i access via mongo console

```
> use raizant
switched to db raizant
> db.getCollection('users')
raizant.users
> db.collection.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e016c9ed023a22f245ee8f1"), "username" : "Elric", "password" : "the_user_pass" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e016caad023a22f245ee8f2"), "username" : "Knautiluz", "password" : "the_user_pass" }
> db.version() 
4.2.2
```

I really don't know why this happening...
My Java MongoVersion: 3.11.0

Comment: You are using different collections in _Java_ and _Mongo Shell_. In Java code you are using "raizant" database and "users" collection. In the shell, you are testing with `db.collection.find()`; it should be `db.users.find()`. Otherwise, your code looks okay.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Nope.

Comment: @prasad_ You're right, I missed that.  I deleted my answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The code you had posted was accurate. No issues.

Comment: @prasad_ you're right, i was in wrong collection... collection.find().first() give me ```Document{{_id=5e018c3b3678df0eb9b7412b, username=Elric, password=the_user_password}}```